# Positive integers relatively prime to all the terms

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Determine **all positive integers relatively prime to all the terms**
of the infinite sequence

$$a_n = 2^n + 3^n + 6^n − 1, n ≥ 1.$$

Comment: @IndritKello Then these are relevant things to take up in the question. Any context and knowledge you have is relevant for us in order to answer it apropriate.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old International Mathematical Olympiad problem. Show that $p \mid 2^{p-2} + 3^{p-2} + 6^{p-2} - 1$ for all primes $p\ge 5$ by using Fermat's Little Theorem. Hence the only solution is $1$, as $(a_1,2) = 2$ and $(a_2,3) = 3$

Answer (score 0):

If  p>3 then, $2^{p-2}+3^{p-2}+6^{p-2}\equiv 1\mod p$. Now, multiply both the sides by 6 to get: $$3 · 2^{p−1} + 2 · 3^{p−1} + 6^{p−1} ≡ 6 \mod p$$

this is clearly a consequence of Fermat’s little theorem. Therefore p divides $a_{p−2}$. Also, 2|$a_1$ and 3|$a_2$. So, there is no number other than 1
that is relatively prime to all the terms in the sequence.

---

Second approach similar to the above one.

Trivially, $a_2 = 48$ is divisible by 2 and 3.Therefore, Let p > 3 be a
prime number. Then
$$6a_{p−2} = 3 · 2^{p−1} + 2 · 3^{p−1} + 6^{p−1} − 6 ≡ 3 + 2 + 1 − 6 ≡ 0\mod p$$
And so the only such number is 1. Proved.