# IMO 2005 problem hint.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Determine all positive integers relatively prime to all the terms of the infinite sequence
$a_n = 2^n + 3^n + 6^n − 1,\ n \ge 1$. ~IMO 2005 P4

I was solving a number theory book in which this was an example question. I know I can find this solution anywhere but I would like a **hint** as to how to solve this problem coz i don't want to see the solution just yet. I think this may use Fermat's little theorem so I was looking at $a_{p-1}$ . Any hint would be appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positive integers relatively prime to all the terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522949/positive-integers-relatively-prime-to-all-the-terms)

Comment: Try to see what is $a_{p-2}$ $mod(p) $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modulo a prime $p\ge5$, $a\cdot2^{p-1}+b\cdot3^{p-1}+c\cdot6^{p-1}\equiv a+b+c$ by Fermat's Little Theorem. Choose $a,\,b,\,c$ so you can divide this by $6$ to prove $p$ is a factor of some $a_n$. What about $p\in\{2,\,3\}$?

Comment: wow this is cool, so i choose a,b,c as 3,2,1 and then divide by 6 to get $a_{p-2}$ is a factor of p for p>=5. Thanks!

Comment: i just have one more question, how would one stumble upon this. i am assuming you have solved this problem, so how did you originally think of this?

Comment: @Aditya_math Working out which integers a sequence is coprime to boils down to finding which primes, if any, can't divide it. So if you want to eliminate candidates with a sequence like this, FLT is a natural starting point in the IMO toolkit. But $a_{p-1}$ isn't an obvious multiple, so you have to try a nearby sequence element.

Comment: @Aditya_math If I was attacking this problem, it might have taken me 12 hours, on and off to solve.  My first step would have been to write a computer program to manually compute $a^n \pmod{b}$ where $a \in \{2,3,6\}$ and $b \in \{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19\}.$  Ultimately, I would focus on a math rather than computer solution, but first, I would look for **patterns** in the data.  Then, I might google something like: *number theory congruence theorem*.

Comment: @user2661923 unfortunately we can't use computers in math contests lol

Comment: @Aditya_math Nor can you spend 12 hours on the problem.  Which is (for some of us) a good reason to avoid direct participation in contests, but still examine the contest problems at home, in our leisure.  Better to do math to live than live to do math.

Comment: @user2661923 computer science 101